# Rewrite drupal views $rows

Tags: views, theming, debugging

I have a view which has to display a list of nodes: title, subtitle with the container that links to the single node.
Difficulty comes when I want to display this view following [this](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-custom-content) from bootstrap 3.
I know how to rewrite each single field, but in this case I should put the node link in a container and then, nested inside, the "title" and "subtitle" fields.
I think I should rewrite the $rows but I'm not sure if it's the correct path. Besides that, I don't know exactly how $rows is organized (and dpm($rows); apparently didn't work, maybe this is related to the theme).

Comment: which hook you are using?

Comment: Hi @ARUN I'm using the row's style override `views-view-fields--view-name.tpl.php`. I would like to access to, for example, node Url in order to display it in the container of the other two fields (as in the link provided).

Comment: You can get node url in view and set it as one of the attribute for container div. Like this: 
    <div class='container' node-path='htp://mysite.com/node/1'>My contents</div>

Then use javascript make redirection while click on div.

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".container").click(function(){
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('node-path');
      });
    });
</script>